# interface for the highest possible number of members

Tags: c#, interface, properties

I have an exercise which wants me to write an interface for the highest possible number of members.

There are three classes below:

```
class Class1 : Example
{
    public int a;
    protected double b;

    public double property1
    {
        set { b = value; }
    }

    public int c { get; }
    public int method1(int x) { return x * x * x; }
}

class Class2 : Example
{
    public int a;
    public double property1 { get; set; }
    public int method1(int x) { return x * x; }
}

class Class3 : Example
{
    public int a;
    public double property1 { get; set; }
}

interface Example
{
    // What goes here?
}
```

The question is write this interface for the highest possible number of members. I didn't understand what this means. Just I tried to write an interface and only could write `double property1 { set; }` because only that property is common for all classes. Is that correct?

Here's my interface

```
interface Example
{
    double property1 {set; }
}
```

Comment: Perhaps you should be asking the person who assigned this to you if you? That being said, I think what you have is correct, except that interfaces should be named with a leading capital `I` (as in: `interface IExample`)

Comment: I'd guess you should move as many member from the classes to the interface. I.e. find the intersection of all the members of all the classes, and put them in the interface.

Comment: This is not a programming problem, its actually reading and comprehension problem. You know what an interface is, and you know what properties are. Now you just have to work out the word maximum, or said another way, an interface that covers as many properties on all class as possible. with that knowledge you should be able to answer this your self.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is correct. Because property1 is the the intersection of all the members of all the classes.